# please help me to my search button

Tags: c#

What is the problem to my code? It always results in "No record found!" even if what am I searching is correct.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\kulet\Desktop\file.txt");

        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of  file.txt = ");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (textBox14.Text == line)

            {
                label28.Text = "File exists!";

            }

            else
            {
                label28.Text = "No record found!";
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);


        }
```

Comment: Did you check to see if `line` contains carriage feed characters?  `\r\n`?

Comment: We'd have to see the input, and the line in the text file you ***think*** matches.

Comment: I see the user just created an account today and asked his/her first question and people dive into giving a down vote. Might not be a very very good educate them. :|

Comment: This is a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the debugger.  Step through this code at runtime and watch how it behaves.  Identify *exactly* where the *expected* behavior differs from the *observed* behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You should place a `break;` after you found a match, since now it will always show the match of the last line:

```
label28.Text = "File exists!";
break;
```

The `break` will bail out of the `foreach`.

Comment: +1. I guess someone read too many comments to [top META - is it ok to answer downvoted questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272422/is-it-ok-to-answer-downvoted-questions?cb=1)...  On other hand votes on to likely to be deleted questions not really matter  :)